# SQL subquery min() not working

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, subquery

How do i get the Select statement that is not working to work (oracle 11g)?

Works:

```
SELECT * FROM (Select statement that returns 4 rows) where Column1= 1
```

Doesn't Work:

```
SELECT * FROM (Select statement that returns 4 rows) where Column1= MIN(Column1)
```

Error= Group function not allowed here

Doesn't Work:

```
SELECT * FROM (Select statement that returns 4 rows) where Column1= MIN(Column1) 
Group by (names of columns in select statement)
```

Same Group function ERROR as above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SELECT * FROM (Select statement that returns 4 rows ORDER BY Column1 ASC) where rownum <= 1

Answer (score 3):

In SQL Server or Oracle, try using window functions:

```
select s.*
from (select s.*, min(column1) over () as mincolumn1
      from  (Select statement that returns 4 rows
            ) s
     ) s
where Column1 = minColumn1;
```

Comment: I don't use SQL Server, rather Oracle 11g

Comment: Hmm it was not tagged with those, you must have gotten mixed up. No big deal though. I appreciate your answer but have posted the answer that worked best for me. Thanks for the time!

Comment: @TheJavaBeast . . . I must've been confused.  Apologies.